# ionic only white screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

my ionic version 5.4.13 
npm vzrsion 6.13.4 
when i create any project on ionic and run it with xcode i get only white screen
and this is the console xcode

```
2020-01-04 13:59:31.567359+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C99122F9-F66A-46D2-BB1F-1B931038D84F/data/Containers/Data/Application/3B7A34CD-DFEC-40F9-B2F8-75CC5FE2CE72/Library/Cookies/io.ionic.starter.binarycookies
2020-01-04 13:59:31.581558+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] Apache Cordova native platform version 4.1.1 is starting.
2020-01-04 13:59:31.581836+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2020-01-04 13:59:31.783256+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] Using UIWebView
2020-01-04 13:59:31.785894+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.056028ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.787517+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.485109ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.787725+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.052929ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.789739+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 1.898050ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.810114+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 20.256996ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.810423+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2020-01-04 13:59:31.811171+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] CDVIonicKeyboard: WARNING!!: Keyboard plugin works better with WK
2020-01-04 13:59:31.811356+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][cdvionickeyboard] 1.055956ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.811448+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 25.646091ms
2020-01-04 13:59:31.909499+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2020-01-04 13:59:32.000722+0100 MyApp[25489:1031357] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.002922+0100 MyApp[25489:1031362] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.003133+0100 MyApp[25489:1031362] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.003537+0100 MyApp[25489:1031362] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.003923+0100 MyApp[25489:1031362] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.004358+0100 MyApp[25489:1031357] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.004694+0100 MyApp[25489:1031360] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.005076+0100 MyApp[25489:1031383] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2020-01-04 13:59:32.011372+0100 MyApp[25489:1031204] Finished load of: file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C99122F9-F66A-46D2-BB1F-1B931038D84F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D060F060-3FEE-4620-A25D-D1864B979649/MyApp.app/www/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are a few errors in your logs.

Often its because you aren't using `https` urls.

However, if your app is loading then you should be using the remote debugging features to figure out why it is failing:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/ios#debugging-ios-apps

Once an app is running on an iOS device or simulator, it can be debugged in Safari.

### Using Safari Web Inspector

Safari has Web Inspector support for iOS simulators and devices. Open the Develop menu and select the simulator or device, then select the Ionic App to open Web Inspector.

> If the Develop menu is hidden, enable it in Safari » Preferences » Advanced » Show Develop menu in menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I formatted my MacBook, first to have sure that your cordova is all right run.

```
ionic cordova platform rm ios 
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

If this part didnt generate any error you can go on.
In your Xcode go to **file -> Workplace settings -> change build system of use shared setting to new build system** and try to run again.